# How to index a middle character in a list in python

Tags: python

Complete the get_mid_letter() function which is passed a list of strings as a parameter. The function returns a string made up of the concatenation of the middle letter of each word from the parameter list. The string returned by the function should be in lowercase characters. If the parameter list is an empty list, the function should return an empty string.

```
def get_mid_letter(a_list):
    middle_list = []
    for item in a_list:
        middle_index = int(len(item) / 2)
        middle_letter = a_list.index(middle_index)
        middle_list = middle_list + [middle_letter] 
    return middle_list.lower()

def test_get_mid_letter():
    print("1.", get_mid_letter(["Jess", "Cain", "Amity", "Raeann"]))
```

In my case, it shows an error message like "2 is not in the list".
What can I do to run my code successfully? Thanks!

Comment: What do you consider the middle letter in a even length word?

Answer (score 2):

`array.index(element)` returns an index not the character or `element`. So you use `array[index_mid]` to get the character and then append it to the `middle_list`

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer pointed out, the mistake is here:

```
middle_letter = a_list.index(middle_index)
```

The `index()` method is looking for an element equal to `middle_index` (in this case, 2) in the list, trying to return the index of that element, but since there's no element equal to 2 in the list you get that error. To find the `middle_letter`, you should directly access the list item:

```
middle_letter = item[middle_index]
```

Be also aware that you're using the `lower()` method on a list, which is gonna cause an error. To get around this problem, you can use `lower()` on `middle_letter` for each loop iteration and simply return `middle_list`, like this:

```
for item in a_list:
    middle_index = int(len(item) / 2)
    middle_letter = item[middle_index]
    middle_letter = middle_letter.lower()
    middle_list = middle_list + [middle_letter] 
return middle_list
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

- The function is supposed to return a string but you declare middle_list as a list not a string.
- The index method returns the position in the list of its argument. You want to use [] for access.
- You are not retrieving the character from the item, but the item from the list.

The corrected code could look like below:

```
def get_mid_letter(a_list):
    middle_list = ""                        # declare the variable as an empty string
    for item in a_list:
        middle_index = int(len(item) / 2)   # get the middle index
        middle_letter = item[middle_index]  # get the char from the string in the list
        middle_list += middle_letter        # concatenate the char and the string
    return middle_list.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you turn each word into a list `['J', 'e', 's', 's']` in your `for` loop then you can just add the letter of the middle index to your growing word of middle letters

```
def middles(listb):
    middle_word = ''
    for i in listb:
        letters = list(i)
        index = int(len(i)/2)
        letter = letters[index]
        middle_word += letter.lower()
    return middle_word

lista = ['Jess', 'Cain', 'Amity', 'Reann']

print(middles(lista))
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 middle.py
> siia
> ```